# WCF web service does not return WSDL

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

Using `wsdl.exe /l:CS /serverInterface`, I generated a C# interface from a WDSL document.  I've implemented that interface on a WCF class.  The resulting service runs locally:

```
http://localhost:51454/TapasSim.svc
```

This shows the default site. The problem appears when I append `?wsdl` to the URL:

```
http://localhost:51454/TapasSim.svc?wsdl
```

[image]

Unlike what I expected, this link does not return a WDSL document!  Instead, it points back to the exact web page you get without the `?wsdl`.  As a result, I cannot reference the web service. If I run `svcutil.exe` it gives this error:

> If you were trying to generate a client, this could be because the
>   metadata documents did not contain any valid contracts or services or
>   because all contracts/services were discovered to exist in /reference
>   assemblies. Verify that you passed all the metadata documents to the
>   tool.

But I would expect that error to have the same cause as the lack of reply to `?wsdl`.

What could cause a WCF `.svc` service not to generate WSDL?

Comment: Did you activate the "metadata HTTP Get" parameter in the service configuration file?

Comment: @JohannBlais: Yes, `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>`.  If you turn that off, the website does not display a link to the WDSL.

Comment: Did you set up the mex endpoint?

Comment: @JohannBlais: No MEX endpoint is configured (how would I go about doing that?)   The wizard generated WCF service does not include a MEX endpoint either, but it still generates WSDL.

Comment: Can you please post your service config file (app.config or web.config)?

Comment: @JohannBlais: [Posted on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/YSjcKdGx)

Comment: Take a look at this for an example of how to add the endpoint: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734786.aspx

Comment: @Kwal: The MEX endpoint seems optional, the wizard generated webservice works fine without it.

Comment: If it works fine without it, why are you posting here? I would argue it's not working fine because it's not doing what you want, which is precisely what the mex endpoint is for, mex being an acronym for metadata exchange and all.

Comment: @Pete: The default `File -> New Project -> WCF Website` generates WDSL without a MEX endpoint.  The link from Kwai's comment literally says `This section is optional with the default configuration introduced in .NET Framework 4.`.  I've actually added MEX and it didn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was mixing two technologies.  `wdsl.exe` belongs to the older "Web References" that predate WCF.  The newer tool `svcutil.exe` is meant for generating WCF "Service Reference" interfaces.

So what happened was that WCF looked for `[ServiceContract]` and `[OperationContract]` attributes.  When it couldn't find any, it silently did nothing.

The silent suppression of this condition is annoying, to say the least.  An error like `No service with [ServiceContract] attribute found` would really have helped.

Note that you can manually add `[ServiceContract]`, but that will leave you with half "Service Reference" half "Web Reference".  The result probably will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with getting the WSDL via the IE window provided by starting the debugging session. I had to use a separate window, ensuring I put the HTTPS in the URL.

We are hosting our services on 443 (SSL). When you start up the debugger, even though the IE windows shows http: (80), it was listening for traffic on 443. 
FYI, this is controlled via the project level setting **SSL Enabled**